# Tabular Forms Column Size Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In Oracle Apex is it possible to change the size of the columns in a tabular form? I haven't been able to find a simple way to do it, and I'm not sure if I can manipulate the CSS or not.

Comment: when you say size, do you mean both height and width?or the width only?if its the width only, you can change it in every column under Appearance.

Comment: oh ok, I'll have to look into that, maybe I just completely missed it. Do you know where it is located? And I am just looking for width of each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apex when you click on the individual column in a tabular form there is a list of different things you can do to the column itself. Under the "Appearance" or under the section "Advanced" there are places to change the width of the column different ways.

Under Appearance there is a field for width
Under Advanced there is a field for cell width

Both of the above change the column width in different ways.

When I asked this question I must have been looking in the wrong place.